# Elevated base android

Tags: android, kotlin, layout

I'm trying to add an elevated base to an layout and I can't manage to do that. If someone know how to help me a little it would be appreciated.

This is the base I want to get:

[image: Elevation base type]

Answer (score 0):

You can simple achieve this using `MaterialCardView` by following code snippet :

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">
        
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            
            <!--Rest of your layout code goes here-->
            
        </LinearLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Happy Coding :)